# gatling and csv ( fetching data from csv)

Tags: csv, gatling

I am working to create a gatling test that would fetch data from a csv. My test is a survey with one question and user picks one option as an answer. It says the test passed but I do not see the option being selected on the survey (It works fine without csv). Here is my sample code:

```
 val uri = """http://localhost:8090/test"""    
val onlyone = csv("onlyone.csv").queue    
    val scn = scenario("onlyone")    
        .exec(http("request_0")
            .get("""/test/login""")
            .headers(headers_0))
        .pause(13)
        .feed(onlyone)
        .exec(http("request_1")
            .post("""/test/login-check""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .formParam("""j_username""", """${username}""")
            .formParam("""j_password""", """${password}"""))
        .pause(4)
        .exec(http("request_36")
            .get("""/test/land/survey/view/${sid}""")
            .headers(headers_0))
        .pause(3)
        .exec(
            http("request_101")
            .post(uri + """/land/survey/showQuestion?mapping=app""")
            .headers(headers_2)
            .body(RawFileBody("onlyone_request_0101.txt"))) 
        .pause(3)
            .exec(http("request_133")
            .post(uri + """/land/survey/saveQuestion?mapping=app""")
            .headers(headers_2)
            .body(RawFileBody("onlyone_request_0133.txt")))
        .pause(4)

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

My csv file has

```
username,password,sid,qid,q1,a1
user1,testpwd1,1234567,2345678,3456789,4567890
```

And these are the contents of the request bodies

```
request_101: {"questionText":"only one","id":"${q1}"}
request_133: {"questionText":"only one","id":"${q1}","selectedOption":"${a1}"}
```

Please help me to find out what did I miss and where. Thank you!

Comment: Also the request bodies show up as txt files, could that be a reason too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use RawFileBody, which, has the name states, treat the files as raw content, not templates.
Please read the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.1/http/http_request.html?highlight=elfilebody#request-body) and use the suited Body type, which is ELFileBody.

Comment: Thank you. I too noticed that the issue was resolved when I used [request body as JSON](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/http_request.html?highlight=request%20bodies#request-body) example.